# Styling Barplots in GGPLOT R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Below is  my data frame

```
Camp <- c("Camp A", "Camp C", "Camp B","Camp C", "Camp C", "Camp B","Camp B", "Camp C", "Camp A")
Beans <- c(1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1)
Maize <- c(1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1)
oranges <- c(0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0)
crops <- data.frame(Camp, Beans, Maize, oranges)
```

I'd like to use the structure of the above dataset to plot a barplot that looks similar to the one generated by this code using `mtcars` dataset.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = reorder(row.names(mtcars), mpg), y = mpg, fill = factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + coord_flip() + theme_minimal() + ggtitle("Fig. A: Default fill colors")
```

My Code to generate the barPlot looks like this. But the output is somehow different. What can I change to produce a barplot that is similar to the `mtcars` one?

```
crops %>%
  gather(-c(Camp), key = "seeds", value="count") %>%
  arrange(desc(count)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=reorder(seeds, count), y=count, fill=factor(Camp))) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + coord_flip()
```

Comment: There is a substantial difference between your data and the mtcars example, which is that in the mtcars each x value belongs to an unique group, whereas in your data you have each seed in more than one camp. So the same kind of graph will be a bit tricky to do.

Comment: I guess the closest you can get is doing `position = "dodge"` within the `geom_bar()` call, but this does not make sense in terms of visualization given that all your values  are either 0 or 1.